# List of bean to a Spring form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I have a bean like this:

```
public class QuestionBean
{
    private int myQuestionId;
    private String myContext;
    private String myQuestionType;
    private String myQuestionAns;

    // setters and getters here
}
```

Which I put in a list `List<UserBean> = new ArrayList<UserBean>;`

I want to use this list with the form, consider something like this:

```
<form:form commandName="questionBean"..
    <form:input path="myQuestionId"...
```

My case is this:

1. Each question will have the attributes I listed in the bean ( that is why I put the bean in a List )
2. There is only 1 Form

**My question is how can I use the List of bean, if the form is only one and I need the a List of bean to be binded to each question?**

Comment: Using [`<c:forEach />`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html)?

Comment: @sp00m If I use <c:forEach /> It will have multiple form. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not necessarily: nest the `<c:forEach />` within your `<form:form />` and iterate over the list of `QuestionBean`s to create a `<form:input />` per iteration.

Comment: @sp00m but the I need to define `commandName` to the form right? I should put there the List of bean?